# Ignore auto repeat in X11 applications

Tags: keyboard, x11, autorepeat

If you press and hold a key in X11 while *AutoRepeat* is enabled, you continuously receive **KeyPress** and **KeyRelease** events.  I know that *AutoRepeat* can be disabled using the function **XAutoRepeatOff()**, but this changes the setting for the whole X server.  Is there a way to either disable *AutoRepeat* for a single application or to ignore repeated keystrokes?

What I'm looking for is a single **KeyPress** event when a key is pressed and a single **KeyRelease** event when a key is released, without interfering with the X server's *AutoRepeat* setting.

Here's a minimal example to get you going (mostly from the [Beginner Xlib Tutorial](http://www.xmission.com/~georgeps/documentation/tutorials/Xlib_Beginner.html)):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>

Display *dis;
Window win;
XEvent report;

int main ()
{
  dis = XOpenDisplay (NULL);
  // XAutoRepeatOn(dis);
  win = XCreateSimpleWindow (dis, RootWindow (dis, 0), 1, 1, 500, 500,
        0, BlackPixel (dis, 0), BlackPixel (dis, 0));
  XSelectInput (dis, win, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask);
  XMapWindow (dis, win);
  XFlush (dis);

  while (1)
    {
      XNextEvent (dis, &report);
      switch (report.type)
 {
 case KeyPress:
   fprintf (stdout, "key #%ld was pressed.\n",
     (long) XLookupKeysym (&report.xkey, 0));
   break;
 case KeyRelease:
   fprintf (stdout, "key #%ld was released.\n",
     (long) XLookupKeysym (&report.xkey, 0));
   break;
 }
    }

  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

When you receive a key release and the next event is a key press of the same key combination, then it's auto-repeat and the key wasn't acutally released. You can use code like this to peek next event

```c
if (event->type == KeyRelease && XEventsQueued(disp, QueuedAfterReading))
{
  XEvent nev;
  XPeekEvent(disp, &nev);
    
  if (nev.type == KeyPress && nev.xkey.time == event->xkey.time &&
      nev.xkey.keycode == event->xkey.keycode)
  {
    /* Key wasn’t actually released */
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've been looking for!

Comment: Is there any reason this uses XEventsQueued with QueuedAfterReading instead of e.g. the cheaper QueuedAlready? Also, isn't XkbSetDetectableAutorepeat the better approach since there is less guessing?

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [XkbSetDetectableAutorepeat](http://linux.die.net/man/3/xkbsetdetectableautorepeat) function to tell the X server to only send KeyRelease events when the user actually releases the key - when you don't want autorepeat events, then you discard any KeyPress without matching KeyRelease.

Answer (score 7):

For your reference, here's a working minimal example that deletes auto-repeated **KeyPress** events.  *Thank you, kralyk!*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <X11/Xos.h>
#include <X11/Xatom.h>
#include <X11/keysym.h>

Display *dis;
Window win;
XEvent report;

int main ()
{
  dis = XOpenDisplay (NULL);
  // XAutoRepeatOn(dis);
  win = XCreateSimpleWindow (dis, RootWindow (dis, 0), 1, 1, 500, 500,
        0, BlackPixel (dis, 0), BlackPixel (dis, 0));
  XSelectInput (dis, win, KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask);
  XMapWindow (dis, win);
  XFlush (dis);

  while (1)
    {
      XNextEvent (dis, &report);
      switch (report.type)
 {
 case KeyPress:
   fprintf (stdout, "key #%ld was pressed.\n",
     (long) XLookupKeysym (&report.xkey, 0));
   break;
 case KeyRelease:
   {
     unsigned short is_retriggered = 0;

     if (XEventsQueued(dis, QueuedAfterReading))
       {
         XEvent nev;
         XPeekEvent(dis, &nev);

         if (nev.type == KeyPress && nev.xkey.time == report.xkey.time &&
             nev.xkey.keycode == report.xkey.keycode)
           {
             fprintf (stdout, "key #%ld was retriggered.\n",
               (long) XLookupKeysym (&nev.xkey, 0));

             // delete retriggered KeyPress event
             XNextEvent (dis, &report);
             is_retriggered = 1;
           }
       }

     if (!is_retriggered)
       fprintf (stdout, "key #%ld was released.\n",
         (long) XLookupKeysym (&report.xkey, 0));
   }
   break;
 }
    }

  return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could set a timer when a key is pressed or released and ignore KeyPress and KeyRelease events that occur within the repetition interval.

Answer (score 0):

another approach. it works for me.

```
char keyz[1024] = {0};
bool physical;
XEvent event, nev;

while (!quit) {
    XNextEvent(display, &event);
    ...
    switch(event.type) {
        case KeyPress:
            physical = (keyz[event.xkey.keycode] == 0);
            keyz[event.xkey.keycode] = 1;
            keyboard(event.xkey.window, true, event.xkey.keycode, physical);
            break;
        case KeyRelease:
            physical = true;
            if (XPending(display)) {
                XPeekEvent(display, &nev);
                if (nev.type == KeyPress && nev.xkey.time == event.xkey.time 
                && nev.xkey.keycode == event.xkey.keycode) physical = false;
            }
            if (physical) keyz[event.xkey.keycode] = 0;
            keyboard(event.xkey.window, false, event.xkey.keycode, physical);
            break;
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I came up with.

```
XEvent event;

while(1)
{
    XNextEvent(display, &event);

    switch(event.type)
    {
        // Other cases
        case ...:
            ...
            break;
        ...

        // On KeyRelease
        case KeyRelease:
        {
            char keys[32];
            XQueryKeymap(display, keys);

            if(!(keys[event.xkey.keycode>>3] & (0x1 << (event.xkey.keycode % 8))))
            {
                // Stuff to do on KeyRelease
                ...
            }
        }
        break;

        // On KeyPress
        case KeyPress:
            // Stuff to do on KeyPress
            ...
            break;
        default:
            ...
    }
}
```

So, everytime I get a KeyRelease event, I use `XQueryKeymap` which will copy to `keys` the bits of pressed keys (8 different keys by `char`).
For the ones who are not used to work with bitwise operatos and shift operator, here's a simple explanation:

`keys[event.xkey.keycode>>3]` search for index `event.xkey.keycode / 8` using "right shift operator" (that allows for "integer division" by 2, 4, 8, 16 and so on, without type cast to float or double and back to integer).

`0x1 << (event.xkey.keycode % 8)` does the oposite. It multiplies the value of `0x1` (`== 1`) by 2 raised to `(event.xkey.keycode % 8)`

The `&` bitwise operator between `keys[event.xkey.keycode>>3]` and `0x1 << (event.xkey.keycode % 8)` will compare if the **only** bit set in the right side operand is set to 1 inside this array index. If so, the key is being pressed.

Finally you just enclose it in `()`, with a `!` right before and if the result becomes true, you're not pressing that key anymore.

One final **Note**: To use this method, you need to keep feeding the XServer with events. If not, XQueryKeymap will freze until it does (better use with threads).