# X sends many key up events when a key is held

Tags: x11, xlib

If I hold a key, I get sent many 'key down' events for that key, annoying but workable; the same approach that win32 api uses.

However, I also get sent a 'key up' event after each 'key down'. This means that if I hold a key I get sent:

```
key down
key up
key down
key up
...
key down
key up
```

This effectively means there is no way to differentiate between a key being held and a key being pressed really fast.

The event mask I am using for my window is `FocusChangeMask | PointerMotionMask | ButtonPressMask | ButtonReleaseMask | ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | StructureNotifyMask`

Is there some cryptic setting somewhere in X that will stop it from sending 'key up' events until the key is actually released. Do I need to 'grab' the keyboard or something first?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to differentiate: look at the time stamp of each event. There is physical travel time for the key (and someone's finger) below which is the autokey stuff.

Comment: So you are saying I have check for all key up and key down events, store them into a buffer, and remove any keyup events that have a keydown with the same time stamp? Seems like a very poor solution to me. what about the final *true* keyup event? That will still have a matching keydown with the same time stamp, so how can I know this one is special and should be considered real

Comment: It's the auto repeat doing it, you can turn it off with `xset r off` but it will stop auto repeat for all programs

Comment: well... not really a 'possible' dupe, it is is a dupe. I just didn't happen to phrase my question in such a way as to find that one. Thanks @BobDalgleish

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the more definitive answer, right from these boards. First result on Google:

[Ignore auto repeat in X11 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100654/ignore-auto-repeat-in-x11-applications)