# XLib jitterless key press and release

Tags: c++, x11, xlib, windowing

I was surprised by the lack of information on that topic. Long story short, I have a piece of code to register key events. It works fine unless the key is pressed for a long time, it starts to repeatedly report itself being pressed and released. It is a common thing, but I don't want it. In any text editor when a key is pressed and then held for some time it just continuously puts it, yet I'd like to avoid that in my application, how do I do so? (Code sample used to catch events provided)

```cpp
    XEvent tmp;
    bool ret = XCheckWindowEvent(d, w, 
        ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask, 
        &tmp);
```

*My first question so please tell me if I did something wrong.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ignore auto repeat in X11 applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100654/ignore-auto-repeat-in-x11-applications)

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to ignore coded in Xlib. You can code the ignorance yourself. The solution can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100654/ignore-auto-repeat-in-x11-applications).

EDIT: **NO NEED TO WRITE YOUR OWN SOLUTION**. This functionality is brought in using `XAutoRepeatOn(Display *)` and `XAutoRepeatOff(Display *)`;